# access_type: 'online' and approval_prompt: 'force' together, request offline access the second time

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I try to authorize my application with both params:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
&response_type=code
&access_type=online
&approval_prompt=force
&redirect_uri=.....
...
```

First time it requests access to "Manage your contacts", that is OK.
But When I try to authorize the second time, it asks the user to allow "Have offline access" permission, that is not OK.

Cleaning cookies doesn't help. Neither revoking access in account settings. Looks like a Google bug.

Actually, I need just to force user to select account on authorize, not force to ask offline access.

I also tried `prompt=select_account` instead, but it is not working at all.

Comment: Why are you asking again?  Why don't you just save the refresh-token and use that the next time? http://goo.gl/gM9GEH

Comment: I have a link Import contacts.  It is redundant in my case to call it twice for same account.
So when use click again, and user have multiple accounts, I want to ask user to select account instead of using same access_token again.

Comment: you could save each of them in a file associate them with the user name.  Then allow the user to pick which account they would like to log in with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem that `prompt=select_account` actually works. It just required several accounts already logged on the same computer.

Comment: This is still going to display it to them again.  You don't need to reautenticate they already gave that.    Wouldn't it be better to store them as options to the user to pick which one they should use?

Comment: because without it, I can store token for first account only, second time it will not show dialog even.